# Show commit number on login page of rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

We are using RoR to create an application where the source code repository is BitBucket.  I would like to put a footnote on the pages that gives the commit id for the commit the deployment is based upon.

I have seen ways, that I don't understand, to get a list of the commits, etc., but I don't see how to get the last one into a view in rails.

Is there a gem that would return such or a list of commits from which I could select the last?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an ENV variable while deploying.

You can get the latest commit hash by:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"
```

Export it to application environment variable, say, LAST_COMMIT before starting the app.

Use this in your view as:

```
<%= ENV["LAST_COMMIT"] %>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're running your app from a git enabled directory, you can call `git rev-parse HEAD` from your template.

```
<%= %x{git rev-parse HEAD}.strip %>
```

There's also the [ruby-git](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git) gem, but it's probably an overkill to accomplish just that.

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitbucket REST API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html) is what you want.  From there, you can ask for the last x commits.  It can then be passed onto your views very easily